# How to create payload body for http post request in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, http, post

I have to sent an HTTP Post Request with some customized parameters as header and a payload message (JSON) but in this specified case I don't know how to costruct it in PHP.

I've this code:

```
$url = 'https://refered.link.com';

$data = array(?????); // WHAT?

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"."Accept: application/json\r\n "."Authorization: token xxxxxxxx\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    /* Handle error */ 
}
var_dump($result);
```

I had to send this body payload:

```
body='{
"request": {
    "branch":"master"
    "message": "Hi there"
}}'
```

In general, with simple payoad like this `$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');` you do this `$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' );`.

But now, is it this: `$data = array('request' => array( "branch" => "master", "message" => "Hi there" ) );` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in my phone right now but I would probably json_encode the arrays you made and see which one looks like the json you need to send.